# Getting Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to this and I have this element and I have to somehow "get it". There are few more element above it, there's just an element I need:

```
<a class="btn_green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ShowPopup( 440, &quot;some_text&quot;, &quot;some_text&quot; ); return false;">
<span>Some text</span>
</a>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Add another parameter to the function, and pass `this` to it.

Comment: Do the other elements have the same `class`?

Comment: Are you trying to get the element you posted code of? `<a class='btn_green ... </a>`

Comment: I would recommend using an event handler instead of the `onclick` attribute. Inside the function you than can refer to `this`

Comment: It's not my website, I can't add anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `$('a.btn_green')` would "get" that `<a>` element but it is not guaranteed to get it uniquely. You may need to use something like the `:nth-child` pseudo-selector to do this if you cannot modify the source. Without more context it is impossible to say what a selector would be that would uniquely retrieve either the `<a>` or the `<span>` element.

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/) is a jQuery tutorial and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) is a CSS selector reference, just in case you need them.

## Edit

One weird thing happening on the page is `$` no longer seems to be bound to jQuery. They must be loading something which uses `$` after jQuery which is causing selectors like `$('a.btn_green')` to return null. You can replace `$` with `jQuery` instead.

I tried the using `jQuery('.btn_green_white_innerfade.btn_medium')` to find the element, but it looks like there are three elements on the page which share that selector. So I looked further up in the source and found that the button I think you want is within a `div` with the id `market_buyorder_info`. This led me to the following code to get the element uniquely:

```
jQuery('#market_buyorder_info').find('.btn_green_white_innerfade.btn_medium')
```

And this code to trigger a click in the console:

```
jQuery('#market_buyorder_info').find('.btn_green_white_innerfade.btn_medium').click()
```

Comment: Ok, here's the page in need it for, the full class name is "btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium", I need to perform click on that green button to open that menu. http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Bill%27s%20Hat

Answer (score 0):

`$('a.btn_green')` will return an array of you could use the Array index to access the proper value if the index is known and does not change

```
var $a = $('a.btn_green');
var el = $a[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByClassName`.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn_green')
```

This will return an array of all the elements that match. If you have only one element you can access it at index 0.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn_green')[0]
```

---

If you added an ID to the element,and then use `getElementById`

```
<a id="YOUR_ID_HERE" class="btn_green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ShowPopup( 440, &quot;some_text&quot;, &quot;some_text&quot; ); return false;">
```

```
document.getElementById('YOUR_ID_HERE')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in standard JS you would do something similar to this:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_green');
```

If you're just looking to get that specific element I would suggest adding an id

```
<a class="btn_green" id="myButton" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ShowPopup( 440, &quot;some_text&quot;, &quot;some_text&quot; ); return false;">
    <span>Some text</span>
</a>
```

And here is the JS

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
```

Answer (score 0):

Details are commented in the Snippet. The anchor in OP's code is atrocious so I made the markup simpler, but the code provided here will work an any anchor(s) under certain conditions described below.

#### SNIPPET

```js
/* Plain JavaScript */
/* If there is only one element that has the class="btn_green" */
// By className
var btnByClassName = document.querySelector(".btn_green");

/* If it is the only link (anchor)
 */
// By tagName
var btnByTagName = document.querySelector("a");

/* If theres more than one element with the class="btn_green" */
// By className
var btnsByClassName1 = document.querySelectorAll(".btn_green");
// or
var btnsByClassName2 = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_green");

/* The two methods above will collect all elements with the
specified className. The group of elements collected is known
as a HTML Collection or NodeList. If you need to specifically
target one of them out of a group, say like the 2nd one, you have
to count from 0. Ex. the second element in a NodeList would be 1.
 */

/* Continuing from the previous example above, we can single out a
single element by placing the 0 count number of that element:
*/
var btnsByClassNameA = document.querySelectorAll(".btn_green")[1];
//or
var btnsByClassNameB = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_green")[1];

/* A different type of NodeList/HTML Collection can be had by
targeting the tagName, this example we are targeting the first
anchor:
*/
var btnsByTagName1 = document.querySelectorAll("a")[0];
//or
var btnsByTagName2 = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

/* Note: Although these methods are able to get a group of
elements, they are able to get an element if it is the only 
one of it's kind by using [0].
 */

/* jQuery */
/* jQuery makes it easier and does most of the thinking for us.
You must make sure that your page has the jQuery library loaded.
Look at the HTML section below, you'll see a <script... tag. You
must have that tag inside the <head></head> or before the </body>
otherwise you code will not function.
*/
/* Note the variable has a $ prefix. This is optional and it's
purpose is to show other developers that the variable represents a
jQuery Object.
*/
// By className
var $btnsByClassName = $(".btn_green");
// By tagName 
var $btnsByTagName = $("a");

/* This part is not part of the question, it is just to show that
these references are working */

$btnsByTagName.on('click', aTonOfStuff);

function aTonOfStuff() {
  btnByClassName.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  btnByTagName.style.color = "lime";
  for (let i = 0; i < btnsByClassName1.length; i++) {
    btnsByClassName1[i].style.fontSize = "40px";
    btnsByClassName2[i].style.fontVariant = "small-caps";
  }
  btnsByClassNameA.style.backgroundColor = "#0E0";
  btnsByClassNameB.style.color = "#000";
  btnsByTagName1.style.lineHeight = "2";
  btnsByTagName2.style.textDecoration = "overline";
  $btnsByClassName.fadeOut("slow");
  $btnsByTagName.fadeIn("slow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Click any link.</p>
<a class="btn_green" href="#/">First Green Button Anchor Link</a>

<a class="btn_green" href="#/">Second Green Button Ancor Link</a>
```

Comment: I used var btnByClassName = document.querySelector(".btn_green"); and then used btnByClassName.click() but it doesn't work for me. When I used it on different element on the same site, it worked.

Comment: Can I even use click() for this?

Comment: Ok, here's the page in need it for, the full class name is "btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium", I need to perform click on that green button to open that menu. http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Bill%27s%20Hat

Comment: There's 9 buttons that have that class and what is the menu's id (better) or class (ok)? "It's not my website, I can't add anything to it" if you can't edit the page how do you plan to use jQuery on it?

Comment: I just need to perform click on that button which has "Place Buy Order" and then put some values into that menu a submit, I guess it is possible.

Comment: It's possible if you can edit the page. Do you have access to it?

Comment: I don't, but I don't want to edit it, I just need to put values there and submit just like you do with mouse and keyboard… Just need to know how to get that element.

Comment: Make an account and pay for whatever you want. This isn't a site to gain illicit knowledge.

Comment: Yes, I have an account and I will pay for it, but I placing those Buy Orders is extremelly tiring so I script to place them automatically (click that button, enter price and quantity and click submit), nothing illegal.

Comment: I just need to find way to tell that script to pick exactly that element and then use click() to perform click.

Comment: It would help if you posted **THE SCRIPT!**

Comment: I haven't written any script, I will, but firstly I need to know how to get that element, but just as an example, I want to use that element like this:

Comment: `$("That Element").click()` just to perform click and then the menu shows and I'll use `.val("value")` to fill every field like price, quantity… with numbers.

Comment: First delete that comment with all the caps, that's disrespectful.

Comment: Done. Sorry for using it.

Comment: No worries, you have a better chance targeting the ancestor of that button and let it get triggered while the event chain makes its way down to the button. Try `$("#market_buyorder_info").trigger('click');`  or `$("#market_buyorder_info").trigger( "submit" )` I strongly recommend that you read  http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I'm using TamperMonkey for it, loaded jQuery and tried it if it does anything... And nothing happened, the same with the second option.
`// ==UserScript==
// @name         Steam Community Market
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        steamcommunity.com/*
// @grant        none
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
$("#market_buyorder_info").trigger('click');`

Comment: Never used tampermonkey. I'm a developer not a script kiddie. Read about `trigger();`, good luck.

Comment: Ok, I guess scripts are below your level, but still doesn't know the answer. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Not reading and expect things to work is below my level, effort to pursue a goal yields better results, good day to you, sir, and good luck.

Comment: Would it be possible to open that menu by calling that onclick event? If yes, how?